# Vertical align middle by overlapping previous DIV

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

Need some CSS fix to align icon in middle by overlapping previous DIV

[image]

Trail code is here

```
<div class="card border-dark col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 pr-0 pl-0">
<div class="card-body card-tpstat">
    <div class="f-16 font-weight-bold text-center pb-2">ORDER STATUS
        <div class="text-warning heading">Attempting to Auto Authorize</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-warning p-1"><i class="far fa-clock fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="pl-1 pl-md-2 col-9">
            <div class="heading text-justify">If we are able to automatically authorize your order, we will send you an email confirmation.If we are unable to automatically authorize your order, we will send you an email with an "Authorization Form" and instructions.</div>
            <div class="content pt-3"> <span class="font-weight-bold text-warning text-justify">Attempting to Auto Authorize</span>
                <i class="fas fa-question-circle form-control-feedback"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Can you add your HTML code in snippet.

Comment: @ShahajiDeshmukh do you mean entire HTML? here you can access the trial version of it https://www.codeply.com/go/nTjQl8FFjM

Comment: Please see below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For snippet result I have commented `.content` media queries. You can check below updated code:

```css
.card-body {
  padding-top: 0!important;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em !important;
  padding-left: 0.5em !important;
  padding-right: 0.5em !important;
}
.card .valign-image-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.card .fa-clock{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/*@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .content {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .heading {
    display: none;
  }
}*/
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 544px) { html {font-size: .9rem !important;} }
@media (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 768px) { html { font-size: .8rem !important; } }
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { html { font-size: .9rem !important; } }
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) { html { font-size: 1rem !important; } }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card border-dark col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 pr-0 pl-0">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-warning">
           <div class="valign-image-wrapper">
              <i class="far fa-clock fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>   
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
           <div class="card-body card-tpstat">
               <div class="f-16 font-weight-bold text-center pb-2">ORDER STATUS
                   <div class="text-warning heading">Attempting to Auto Authorize</div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="heading text-justify">If we are able to automatically authorize your order, we will send you an email confirmation.If we are unable to automatically authorize your order, we will send you an email with an "Authorization Form" and instructions.</div>
           <div class="content pt-3">
               <span class="font-weight-bold text-warning text-justify">Attempting to Auto Authorize</span>
               <i class="fas fa-question-circle form-control-feedback"></i>
           </div>
        </div>        
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```